# Automatically overlap SVG edges

Tags: javascript, svg, inkscape

I am working on a large number of complex SVG files in which shapes share some exact paths (i.e. they are arranged edge-to-edge) after being vectorized from bitmap. These shapes are defined by paths, have fulled colors, but do not have outlines.

In the next step of my workflow this creates an edge artifact. I have found the best way to solve this is to manually move nodes so there is a slight (e.g. 1px) overlap of edges. I need to do this process to around 1k shapes across 30+ illustrations in development, which is why I would like an automated process for my workflow. I am not sure if this can be done through an SVG editor plugin or perhaps a javascript application.

Because shapes are complex and have hollowed portions sometimes, each node needs to be moved on a perpendicular from the filled edge.

The end goal is to have all existing edge-to-edge portions to have a miniscule overlap to eliminate edge artifact.

Example of SVG shape formatting:

```
  <path
 style="fill:#ab1d0f;fill-opacity:0.65151511;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.75px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
 d="M 470.69864,588.16878 C 455.52231,786.44675 423.79624,835.14131 590.12728,799.75617 640.3406,789.07383 635.02232,779.84655 760.89356,718.61568 930.36806,636.17371 742.59028,617.50816 658.00951,552.62236 572.1577,486.76149 535.54865,393.28533 504.21382,416.85787 c -68.79903,51.75605 -26.87605,84.5711 -33.51518,171.31091 z"
 id="shape1"/>
```

Example of pre-processed SVG:

[image]

In the above image:

- There are 4 filled shapes (pink, red, black, yellow)
- Black shape is selected and we see four nodes
- I need to move each node outward from it's filled side
- Each node moves in direction of green arrow

After processing:

[image]

- Yellow shape is selected and we can see nodes are now overlapping with edge of black shape.
- mouse hover on pink also reveals it's edge is overlapping as well

Comment: Remember that questions about code (and SVG markup counts for the purposes of SO questions) really need to show code, so that people can understand what you're describing. Without a clear, minimal, runnable code example, no one knows what you mean when you say "this creates an edge artifact" . If this is your first question, please remember take the [tour] and read through ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask). You've written a good amount of explanation but it's still missing some critical information.

Comment: Thanks. I updated. I am specifically looking to batch modify coordinates in multiple SVG paths. Each node just needs to be moved away from filled center of shape. This is different from scaling up object. If object is donut then hole in middle gets smaller as well because inside nodes are moving away from filled donut.

Comment: The image you show have outlines, though... so that's a little in conflict with what you describe in your first paragraph?

Comment: Those are not outlines those are filled shapes. The only outline there is the thin red line from mousing over and object in Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should simply enlarge you shapes with a filter? Something like this:

```
<filter id="enlarge">
   <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
</filter>
```